# Date formatting for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying a date which takes the following format;

> Sun Feb 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

All what i want is `Sunday February 24 2013`. How could i format the above date to the format i want ?

```
var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                  theDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
```

Comment: See this post [formatting-a-date-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Since you're already using the datePicker, `$.datepicker.formatDate()` does exactly what you wan't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the DatePicker

```
$(this).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD MM d yy"
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eJseP/

---

**Edited, by request:**

```
<input type="text" id="myinputfield" value="" />
<script>
    $("#myinputfield").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "DD MM d yy"
    });
<script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to display the string with the formatted date?

Comment: Whats the Id of your text field? if the textfield's id is "myinputfield" you should use "#myinputfield" instead of "this" when calling the function datepicker

Comment: Ok, so what you say is that i should get rid of my 2 lines (shown in the above post) and add your code instead ?